# ngx datatable set nowrap to custom column

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

I'm looking for a way in ngx-datatable, to disable the wrap of texts in a column, I found a way, here's the [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-datatable-angular-p3e4mu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbasic%2Fbasic.component.html).
In

> Basic datatable with fixed width, align and text-wrap

In the **columnsWithFeatures** it defines a noWrap for the columns, and it magically fixes my wrap problem... but I doesn't use a columns object, instead I gotta use custom columns like

```
<ngx-datatable-column name="Type" prop="tipus">
  <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-value="value">
    <mat-icon *ngIf="value == '0'" [matTooltipPosition]="'above'" color="primary"
              matTooltip="Entruster">
      supervisor_account
    </mat-icon>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="value == '1'" [matTooltipPosition]="'above'" color="primary"
              matTooltip="Deliverer">
      local_shipping
    </mat-icon>
  </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```

I've tried to set noWrap for my custom columns like name and prop, but it doesn't accept that there. How should I make it work?